# Dynamo DB Query using begins_with in ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-dynamodb

Below is the my dynamodb data

```
Table Name : Inventory
PartitionKey: Name (string)
SortKey : ID (String)
```

Below is sample data.

```
Name     ID
Fruits  Mango
Fruits  Mango-Green
Fruits  Mango-Green-10
Fruits  Mango-Green-20
Fruits  Apple
Fruits  Apple-Red
Veggie  Onion
Veggie  Onion-White
Veggie  Onion-White-10
```

How can I add the search to the below code to return all the rows that begins_with `"Mango-Green"` ?  I cant modify the keys or the table data now.

```
  table_name: 'Inventory',
  key_condition_expression: "#Name = :Name AND #ID = :ID",
  select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
  expression_attribute_names: {
      "#ID" => "ID",
      "#product" => "product"
  },
  expression_attribute_values: {
      ":ID" => ID,
      ":Name" => 'Fruits'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

more info about ruby interface into code as comments

```rb
require 'dotenv/load'
require 'aws-sdk-dynamodb'

# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/DynamoDB.html
client_dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(
  region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
)

# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Client.html#query-instance_method
fruits = client_dynamodb.query({
  table_name: "Inventory",
  projection_expression: "name, id",
  key_conditions: {
    "id" => {
      attribute_value_list: ["Mango-Green"],
      comparison_operator: "BEGINS_WITH",
    }
  },
  scan_index_forward: false, # true => asc ; false  => desc
}).items
```